# Swift How to map/translate values?

Tags: swift, swiftui

How do I translate/map one value range to another? e.g.:

```
ValueRangeA: -90 - -180
ValueRangeB: 0.0 - 1.0
```

I would like to use a specific input as an opacity value.
Is there something similar to After Effects Expression/JS function?

```
y = linear(a,40,200,0,100)
```

This my SwiftUI Code

```
import SwiftUI

struct Demo: View {
    
    @State var swipeYValue: Double = 0.0
    @State var opacityValue: Double = 0.5
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.red)
            .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
            .opacity(opacityValue)
            .gesture(
                DragGesture()
                    
                    .onChanged({
                        action in
                        self.swipeYValue = Double(action.translation.height)
                    })
        )
    }
}
```

Update: Maybe it isn't a specific SwiftUi-problem. Is there something similar in swift?

Comment: I am also want to change the opacity of view on the base of drag gesture. did you find the solution

Answer (score 0):

To change the value on swipe you can use normalised the height parameter with 100. Now you can drag on you rectangle and your view opacity will change accordingly. As you drag down opacity will start increasing to 1 and on the opposite side its star decreasing toward 0.

```
    struct TestView: View {
    
    @State var swipeYValue: Double = 0.0
        @State var opacityValue: Double = 0.5
        
        var body: some View {
            
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.red)
                .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                .opacity(opacityValue)
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture()
                        
                        .onChanged({
                            action in
//                            self.swipeYValue = Double(action.translation.height)
                            opacityValue = Double(action.translation.height / 100)
                        })
                        .onEnded({ _ in
                            opacityValue = 0.5
                        })
            )
        }

}
```